# Save Excel File As to newly created folder

Tags: excel, save

I'm writing an **applescript** that basically asks for `'Job Number', 'Client Name' and 'Job Description'` and then creates a new folder (with some sub folders) to a location on the server whose name is a combination of these three questions. It then opens an Excel template file (a job sheet) and fills in a couple of fields.

So far so good.

Where I am running aground is saving the Excel file to a sub-folder of the newly created job folder with a file name that is jobNumber & "_jobsheet.xls".

If you look at the line...

```
save workbook as myWorkbook filename "MATRIX:11. Misc. Design Work:01. Live Jobs:" & folderName & jobNumber & "_jobsheet.xls"
```

...the path is where the new folder is created to but I can't seem to add the `folderName` to the path without it becoming part of a (rather long) `filename`. It will save the file to '01. Live Jobs' but not in to the new job folder that has just been created.

In short, what I am trying achieve is save the Excel file as jobNumber_jobsheet.xls to a folder 'MATRIX:11. Misc. Design Work:01. Live Jobs:folderName'

I feel like I am close but am starting to go round in circles and any help is much appreciated.

**Here is the script in full;**

```
set jobNumber to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Job Number" default answer "")
set clientName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Client name" default answer "")
set jobDescription to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Job Description" default answer "")

set folderName to jobNumber & "-" & clientName & "_" & jobDescription
set filePath to "MATRIX:11. Misc. Design Work:01. Live Jobs:"
tell application "Finder"
    set newfo to make new folder at filePath with properties {name:folderName}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Images & Logos"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Job Sheet"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"~Proofs"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"To Print"}
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open file "ACCOUNTS:Misc Design Jobs:Templates:blank_jobsheet.xlt"
    set jobNumberRange to range "F1" of worksheet 1 of active workbook
    set value of jobNumberRange to jobNumber
    set clientNameRange to range "B4:C4" of worksheet 1 of active workbook
    set value of clientNameRange to clientName
    set jobDescriptionRange to range "B6:C6" of worksheet 1 of active workbook
    set value of jobDescriptionRange to jobDescription
    set myWorkbook to active workbook
    save workbook as myWorkbook filename "MATRIX:11. Misc. Design Work:01. Live Jobs:" & folderName & jobNumber & "_jobsheet.xls" with overwrite
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a colon between the folder name and filename:

```
 ...Live Jobs:" & folderName & ":" & jobNumber & "_jobsheet.xls"
```

Comment: Brilliant! I knew I was close! Thanks so much.